# como hago que en este diagrama el dato "duration" me aparesca a 2 meses

Tags: html, google-chart-api

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Fecha Inicial');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Fecha Final');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Duracion');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Percentaje Complado');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencias');

      data.addRows([
        ['Tema', 'Definir el Tema',
         new Date(2018, 0, 20), new Date(2018, 2, 20), null, 90, null],
        ['Objetivos', 'Definir Objetivos',
         new Date(2018, 1, 20), new Date(2018, 2, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],
        ['Justificacion', 'Justificacion',
         new Date(2018, 5, 20), new Date(2018, 6, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],
        ['Metodologia', 'Elegir la Metodologia',
         new Date(2018, 3, 20), new Date(2018, 4, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],
        ['Bibliografia', 'Crear la Bibliografia',
         new Date(2018, 4, 20), new Date(2018, 5, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],
         ]);

      var options = {
        height: 275
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El primer ítem *Definir el Tema* lo tienes a dos meses: 0 es enero y 2 es marzo... Simplemente dale un plazo de dos meses de diferencia al ítem que lo requiera, por ejemplo, en *Elegir Metodología* pones `new Date(2018, 3, 20), new Date(2018, 5, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],`

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Fecha Inicial');
      data.addColumn('date', 'Fecha Final');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Duracion');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Percentaje Complado');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencias');

      data.addRows([
        ['Tema', 'Definir el Tema',
         new Date(2018, 0, 20), new Date(2018, 2, 20), null, 90, null],
        ['Objetivos', 'Definir Objetivos',
         new Date(2018, 1, 20), new Date(2018, 2, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],
        ['Justificacion', 'Justificacion',
         new Date(2018, 5, 20), new Date(2018, 6, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],
        ['Metodologia', 'Elegir la Metodologia',
         new Date(2018, 3, 20), new Date(2018, 5, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],
        ['Bibliografia', 'Crear la Bibliografia',
         new Date(2018, 4, 20), new Date(2018, 5, 20), null, 90, 'Tema'],
         ]);

      var options = {
        height: 275
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: y crear un formulario que para esa variable porcentaje reciba un parametro ingresado, como por ejemplo, ingresar porcentaje y me refleje eso en el grafico

Comment: Para ello debes crear un formulario en HTML que envíe el porcentaje por POST, _por ejemplo_, y luego recibes los datos en el código de tu gráfico... Algo así:`<?php if (isset($POST_["porcentaje"])) {$porcentaje = $POST_["porcentaje"];}?>` y en la línea del gráfico iría esto:`new Date(2018, 3, 20), new Date(2018, 5, 20), null, <?= $porcentaje; ?>, 'Tema'],` pero este es un tema nuevo y un poco amplio, así que te sugiero que intentes hacerlo primero y si tienes dudas, abres una nueva pregunta. Por lo pronto, si mi respuesta satisface tu duda inicial, te invito a que la marques como aceptada.